# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string / Select sum where date query

Tags: oracle, date, select, ora-01830

I am trying to execute my query through Java like this:

```
public ResultSet execSumStatment2() throws SQLException{
String query = "Select SUM(A) as NCCSeptember from NCC where Datum >= '01-09-2013 00:00:00' and Datum <= '30-09-2013 23:59:59'";
return execStatement(query);
}
```

Then i call execSumStatement in the class:

```
sql.execSumStatement2 () ;
```

When I run it I get the following error message:

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at com.bachelorarbeit.SQLExecutor.execStatement(SQLExecutor.java:20)
at com.bachelorarbeit.SQLExecutor.execSumStatment2(SQLExecutor.java:56)
at com.bachelorarbeit.Test.doGet(Test.java:63)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I execute the same query in SQL Developer it works just fine. I already made a search over the internet, and I guess the problem is the datatype of the date in the query, which should be Date, but everything I tried didn't work...

Comment: You can put:
     Select SUM(A) as NCCSeptember from NCC where Datum between to_date('01-09-2013 00:00:00') and to_date('30-09-2013 23:59:59')

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think you should not rely on the implicit conversion. It is a bad practice.

Instead you should try like this:

```
datenum >= to_date('11/26/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

or like

```
datenum >= date '2013-09-01'
```

Comment: Format for date literal (second option) is incorrect. It should be `yyyy-mm-dd`(`date '2013-09-01'`). Moreover, when comparing dates take into consideration the time portion of a date.

Comment: I just tried the first solution and it worked ! If i change the settings of the datestamp to "DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS" in SQL Developer to add the time and change the order of Month and Days, should "to_date('26/11/2013 14:34:45','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mm:ss')" work ?

PS: Thanks a lot for the quick answer !

Comment: I got this error because I simply forgot one 'y' in the 'YYYY' pattern for the year

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```
Select To_date ('15/2/2007 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
       To_date ('28/2/2007 10:12', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  From DUAL;
```

**Source:** http://notsyncing.org/2008/02/manipulando-fechas-con-horas-en-plsql-y-sql/

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Developer ..Go to Preferences-->NLS-->and change your date format accordingly

Answer (score 1):

What you have written in your sql string is a `Timestamp` not `Date`. You must convert it to `Date` or change type of database field to `Timestamp` for it to be seen correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows it works for me

```
select * from nm_admission where trunc(entry_timestamp) = to_date('09-SEP-2018','DD-MM-YY');
```

**OR**

```
select * from nm_admission where trunc(entry_timestamp) = '09-SEP-2018';
```

You can also try using to_char but remember to_char is too expensive

```
select * from nm_admission where to_char(entry_timestamp) = to_date('09-SEP-2018','DD-MM-YY');
```

The TRUNC(17-SEP-2018 08:30:11) will give 17-SEP-2018 00:00:00 as a result, you can compare the only date portion independently and time portion will skip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`Select to_date('08/15/2017 12:00:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual;`

If you are using it in an SP then your variable datatype should be `Varchar2`

and also in your ado.net code the datatype of your input parameter should be

`OracleDbType.Varchar2`

Basically I had to put a DateFrom and DateTo filter in my SP so I passed dates as String in it.

**Note:** This is one of the solution which worked for me, there could be more solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS DATE) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by providing more insights on the solution you presented.