# Converting string to date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to convert **2014-11-18T14:08:43+00:00** which is in varchar in my sql developer to date format in order to filter a few entries.

**I tried**

`to_date(LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')`

**but it gives an error**

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string.

Kindly help..

Comment: why is your date colunm varchar?

Comment: what version of sql server are you running? for me it says to_date isn't recognized

Comment: SQL Server returning ORA error codes? Very odd.

Comment: do you need the time aswell or just the dates?

Comment: @Isha How could you get an `ORA` error in `sql server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you didn't mean to put up sql server but instead you need to use oracle (seeing as you are using to_date and you are getting an ora exception)
I added a quick datetime conversion for date and timestamp (no milliseconds) for your date format:

```
SELECT to_Date(concat
               (substr
                (myvar,0,10),
                concat(' ',
                       substr(myvar,12,8)
                      )
               ),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') AS mydate
FROM mytable
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/233262/30)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @varDate as nvarchar(50) = '2014-11-18T14:08:43+00:00'

select CAST(substring(@varDate,0,CHARINDEX('T',@varDate)) as date)
```

Comment: How could sql server syntax work for an Oracle database?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I'm wondering the same thing, or how she got ora error when the tag is sql server, this is really confusing

Comment: it was tagged previously with `sql` `sql-server`, it later has edited

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use it like this

```
declare @Date as nvarchar(100) = '2014-11-18T14:08:43+00:00'
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@Date) AS Date
```

OR go for this answer which is accepted in this question

> [ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string / Select sum where date query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219363/ora-01830-date-format-picture-ends-before-converting-entire-input-string-sele)

Comment: @Isha try this solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;

```
Select CAST ('2014-11-18T14:08:43+00:00' as date)
```

The assumption is you are in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.
>   to_date(LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')

`2014-11-18T14:08:43+00:00` is **TIMESTAMP** and not **DATE**.

First of all, you should *never ever* store **DATE/TIMSTAMP** as **string**. It is a database design flaw.

Anyway, you could convert it to **TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2014-11-18T14:08:43+00:00',
  2                         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
  3                         AS tm_stamp
  4  FROM dual;

TM_STAMP
----------------------------------------------------------------
18-NOV-14 02.08.43.000000000 PM +00:00

SQL>
```

Comment: @Isha `ORA` error proves that your database is `Oracle` and not `sql server`.